# Solr: Support for transliteration / transcription of Greek

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have indexed some fields that contain Greek letters (like for example `Στεφαν`). Like in google I want to find these documents when I search for `Stefan`. Is there any support for transliteration / transcription of Greek words?

So far I have already tried the `solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` and the `solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory`. Both seem to work for languages like French (search for `Stephane` returns also `Stéphane`) or Polish (search for `Wroclaw` also returns `Wrocław`). But it doesn't seem to work for Greek (search for `Στεφαν` does not return `Stefan`).

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: did you analyse the same in solr web interface?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a character filter and map a file with certain characters to their ascii equivalent.

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="greek_character.txt"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

your indexed objects may have a getter function for that returns a searchable word

pseudocode :

```
public function returnIndexName(w){
   if(w.isGreek){

     return matchingLetter(lowercase(w.name),
```

[image]

```
     )
   }

}
```

http://www.typegreek.com/alphabet.key/

and add this property to your index

maybe be a bit hacky, but the logic to convert the greek word shouldnt be to difficult

```
for letter in word, returnword += alphabetkeys[letter]
```

i think thats the/a way to go

Comment: This could be used to develop a special "GreekFoldingFilter".

Answer (score -1):

You can try by adding `<filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>`

to your fieldType.

For more such language specific you can take a look at

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Greek

Comment: Unfortunately adding the `solr.GreekStemFilterFactory` did not solve the problem.

Comment: can you share the fieldType of yours?

Comment: The field type looks like this: `<fieldType name="text_mim" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>`

Comment: can you try this one for your field <fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but by searching for `firstName:Στεφαν AND lastName:Miller` I did not find the person with firstName:Stefan and lastName:Miller.

Comment: did you tried to analyse the same in web interface...?

Comment: Yes, I did all of my queries through the web interface. There is also no issue with the encoding, as the query for `firstName:Στεφαν` finds all persons with first name = `Στεφαν`.

Comment: web interface is meaning solr analysis tool which is available at http://localhost:8989/solr if you have core created http://localhost:8989/solr/coreName click on analysis page and check...